# Check if value in two columns, otherwise remove it from dataframe

Tags: r

I want to create a function that checks whether a certain value is present in two columns. If the answer is affirmative, I want it to do nothing. If a value is only present in one of the columns, I want to remove it from the other one, too. The end result should be two identical columns.

I tried to use the %in% function, however I don´t seem to be able to get quite where I want.

```
testfunction <- function(dataframe, conditionvariable, idvariable){
  #catches all levels of condition variable
  conditions <- unique(dataframe$Group)
  #We only want to compare two conditions
  dataGroupA <- dataframe %>% filter(Group == conditions[1])
  dataGroupB <- dataframe %>% filter(Group == conditions[2])
  
  #check for each participant number if there are values in both groups. If there are not, remove the participant from the dataset. Finally, return the new data set with the removed participants.
  for(ppnumber in dataGroupA){
    for(ppnumber in dataGroupB){
      
      if(ppnumber %in% dataGroupA){
        if(!ppnumber %in% dataGroupB){
          dataframeUpdated <- dataframe %>% filter(participant == ppnumber)
}      
}#close if Clause
      
      if(ppnumber %in% dataGroupB){
        if(!ppnumber %in% dataGroupA){
          dataframeUpdated <- dataframe %>% filter(participant == ppnumber)
}      
}#close if Clause
      else{
        dataframeUpdated <- dataframe
      }#close else loop
    }#close for loop groupB
  } #close for loop groupA
} #close function


#Sample Data
group <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
participant <- c(1,1,1,2,2,4,3,4)
latency <- c(1.1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1.5)
dataframe <- as.data.frame(cbind(participant, group, latency))

#expected output:

dataframeExpected <- dataframe[1:5,]

#PP1 and PP2 both have some data in both groups/conditions. 
#PP3 and PP4 do only have data in one condition, hence they should be removed.
```

Any help is appreciated.

The expected output is a dataframe that only contains the data of participants of which there is data in both groups (group being a within-subject factor).

There was a solution provided, which only works sometimes.
Here is code reproducing when it does not work:

```
#first some data
dfn <- structure(list(X = c(11L, 12L, 18L, 20L, 27L, 29L, 33L, 36L, 
37L, 47L, 51L, 55L, 57L, 58L, 61L, 68L, 71L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 80L, 
84L, 86L, 87L, 90L, 92L, 95L, 98L, 100L, 101L, 103L, 106L, 109L, 
114L, 116L, 117L, 119L, 122L, 123L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 136L, 138L, 
140L, 141L, 143L, 144L, 146L, 147L, 149L, 154L, 158L, 160L, 161L, 
163L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 174L, 177L, 178L, 180L, 182L, 186L, 
193L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 200L, 201L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 
209L, 210L, 213L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 220L, 222L, 224L, 226L, 
227L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 234L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 
246L, 249L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 
263L, 266L, 267L, 269L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 279L, 
280L, 282L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 291L, 293L, 294L, 
295L, 298L, 300L, 301L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 308L, 309L, 311L, 312L, 
313L, 315L, 316L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 
328L, 330L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 336L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 342L, 
344L, 345L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 353L, 354L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 
360L, 362L, 366L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 
384L, 385L, 387L, 388L, 389L, 392L, 395L, 399L, 401L, 402L, 404L, 
405L, 406L), participant = c(31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L), latency = c(1.241730792, 
2.158541302, 0.891793295, 1.725196538, 1.141727408, 1.291906705, 
2.391879296, 1.475077386, 1.102099018, 1.208499439, 1.608445841, 
1.275157173, 1.475068786, 1.225057273, 1.29179213, 1.375061518, 
1.62511187, 1.458515113, 1.175086097, 1.325173291, 1.141661382, 
1.541854966, 0.891640437, 1.708388748, 2.508667999, 1.791765498, 
1.208331599, 1.758546351, 1.325188826, 1.275036217, 1.475070173, 
2.008490728, 1.591703522, 1.101920637, 1.341740835, 1.491791409, 
1.541778953, 1.391753069, 1.541872166, 1.102017734, 1.258391273, 
0.974974463, 0.90828122, 1.291834021, 1.425102049, 2.308734192, 
1.508330934, 1.158520772, 1.641787886, 0.724940479, 2.008608631, 
1.641750434, 0.708203154, 1.758491421, 1.658470282, 0.691591222, 
1.341717254, 1.608539054, 1.458390551, 2.325271775, 2.241825948, 
1.791821259, 1.891815766, 1.208526903, 1.325015161, 0.758281414, 
1.10965261976, 1.37513309242, 1.22519903524, 1.30854166216, 1.10197473366, 
1.15839843002, 1.20852218725, 1.19183313276, 1.10203687582, 1.30849283617, 
1.19171578394, 0.958308434856, 1.42508124255, 1.10204575328, 
0.908274006988, 1.12500395324, 1.40856585321, 1.1019153657, 0.958443538575, 
0.941628812658, 1.47504576049, 0.924951964663, 1.1019153657, 
1.10196752073, 1.54169378451, 1.22501177649, 1.10191869475, 0.90829092963, 
0.908266239217, 0.958333402688, 1.45836142215, 0.85834499886, 
1.10202744353, 0.958313705843, 0.908268736001, 0.808449281176, 
1.10205435331, 1.10191786249, 0.79179351713, 0.858266211475, 
1.10196668847, 1.42508151998, 1.1249706628, 1.72516352544, 1.15850995301, 
0.974938121387, 1.29183679471, 1.191713842, 0.808320835546, 1.1916525321, 
0.808365500225, 0.808249815932, 1.22504423468, 1.30837049379, 
0.741602346754, 1.12511603107, 1.42505932635, 0.974968360207, 
1.22501649264, 1.275043985, 0.94168374189, 1.10199997892, 1.49183746052, 
1.30836716475, 1.39183823729, 1.30836938411, 2.07520588753, 0.958485983891, 
1.65851910788, 0.924998848706, 1.72524425476, 1.10198028207, 
0.94175892281, 1.10193367545, 1.10194754647, 1.10203992745, 1.10204769522, 
1.22500012484, 1.10193728191, 0.891663462462, 0.925117029782, 
1.10200219828, 1.29175023955, 1.3083338743, 0.875121163346, 1.10196585621, 
1.77526425677, 1.2251629706, 0.891650423704, 1.10204408875, 1.10197695303, 
1.32506981284, 1.10202855321, 1.10197279172, 1.4085669629, 1.15834682983, 
1.52508545934, 0.791753568597, 0.908250148836, 1.40841188491, 
1.40849982717, 0.975095696156, 1.10194144322, 1.20839290936, 
1.52507602705, 1.10189705596, 0.891815488823, 1.10202994032, 
0.841608228066, 1.37504098886, 1.49169708581, 1.10196890783, 
1.50853206341, 0.924902583838, 0.891599100936, 1.10198915952, 
0.874946388514, 0.758285575417, 1.45891598546, 1.22515409314, 
1.82517939388, 1.5250998852, 1.4585664358, 1.10193228835, 1.10204436617, 
1.30839546162, 0.924993577719, 1.17497485184, 1.12509245034, 
1.10189400434, 1.14180120167, 1.10199248857, 0.908294258675, 
1.15838012028), Group = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
200L), class = "data.frame")
#There clearly is more than 1 value per group per participant.

groups <- aggregate(
  Group ~ participant,
  dfn,
  function(x) identical(sort(unique(x)), unique(dfn$Group))
)

compliant_participants <- groups[which(groups$Group),][["participant"]]
data_cleaned <- dfn[dfn$participant %in% compliant_participants,]
#The code falsely states that these participants are not compliant.
```

Comment: Could you please add the expected output????

Comment: I elaborated on it a bit.

Comment: Hi. I mean adding the dataframe you want to obtain because we can not easily see how columns must be filled of what the final results is!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I added new sample data and also sample code that reproduces what the result output should be!

Comment: `dataframe[dataframe$participant %in% dataframe$group, ]` produces your example output. Why do you say that `%in%` wasn't working for you?

Comment: Probably because I used it wrong: I used it as part of a if-loop. 
Your code seems to do what I require!

Comment: I think this only coincidentally works because the group ids and participant ids in the example happen to be the same, unless your intention is to only ever get participants 1 and 2 when you have groups 1 and 2.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed by now :/ Thanks anyway!

Comment: No! I want to get all participants who have data in both groups of the withinsubject factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> groups <- aggregate(
    group ~ participant,
    dataframe,
    function(x) identical(sort(unique(x)), sort(unique(dataframe$group)))
  )

> compliant_participants <- groups[which(groups$group),][["participant"]]

> dataframe[participant %in% compliant_participants,]

  participant group latency
1           1     1     1.1
2           1     2     1.4
3           1     1     1.3
4           2     2     1.5
5           2     1     1.3
```

Comment: What would cause groups to assign FALSE to a participant ID?

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example of the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: I added it below the original question: What happens is that the original dataframe clearly has at least one value per group, but the groups function still assigns them as false and falsely denotes them as noncompliant.

Comment: My mistake - `unique(dfn$Group)` also has to be ordered. I have updated the solution to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out by now, too!